# Making multiple pivot items visible

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I would like to make some pivot items visible and others invisible. But the problem is some items are not available in the pivotfields. The countries GE,KG,KZ,MN,AZ,TM will be avilable on next months.

But i would like to create a single code. If the items are present in the pivotfields then it must be visible orelse it must invisble. How can i change the code. Help me

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MainTable").PivotFields("Country Code")
        For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
          .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
          .PivotItems("DE").Visible = True
        Next i
        .PivotItems("UA").Visible = True 'Available
        .PivotItems("BY").Visible = True 'Available
        .PivotItems("MD").Visible = True 'Available
        .PivotItems("GE").Visible = True 'Not available
        .PivotItems("KG").Visible = True 'Not available
        .PivotItems("KZ").Visible = True 'Not available
        .PivotItems("MN").Visible = True 'Not available
        .PivotItems("AZ").Visible = True 'Not available
        .PivotItems("TM").Visible = True 'Not available
        .PivotItems("DE").Visible = False
      End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this this way:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MainTable").PivotFields("Country Code")
  For Each Pi In .PivotItems
    Pi.Visible = InStr(1, "UA,BY,MD,GE,KG,KZ,MN,AZ,TM", Pi.Name) > 0
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Instead of specifying a list of `PivotItem` names to make visible, why not scan through all available `PivotItem`'s names and set their visibility based on their presence within a string..

Comment: Thank you. But whether it will work for other items if it is available on next month ?

Comment: If they're in that string, then yes, provided the macro is run to re-set the visibility.

Comment: This process applies the filter at the PivotItem level, one at a time. So each time this macro is run, it examines each PivotItem available at that time and sets the visibility (based on its presence in the string). Obviously, if you want to clear the filters for another reason then do so, but it's not necessary for this macro to function.

Comment: If you're in any way unsure @Deepak, add some 'dummy' data to your table and test the different scenarios you're worried about.

Comment: Efficiency suggestion: Turn .ManualUpdate to TRUE at the start, and then to FALSE after you've finished. Otherwise the PivotTable will try to update after each and every PivotItem's Visible status is changed. See my post at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/14/filtering-pivots-based-on-external-ranges/ for more info.